# Windows 10 default search location in folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, search

When you use search in Windows 10 File Explorer in a folder, it includes all subfolders by default. You can disable it for every search to ignore subfolders, but how can I make it default?

[image: File Explorer search tab]